# Filter Empty Directories in Package Explorer View

Tags: eclipse

Is there a way in eclipse to filter/hide empty directory trees in the package explorer view?

This is different than filtering directories like '.svn' or maven's target, or filtering empty packages.  It's more trying to clean up empty directories trees that show up as a result of filter rules.

Context- We have a generic project in our workspace that uses filters to ignore non text based files(mp3s, jpgs, etc).  It allows us to quickly edit our files in eclipse.  The problem is because of the filters there are a lot of empty folders present.  If eclipse can ignore any empty folders due to filters it would make the project cleaner.

Update- I filed a bug report in eclipse's buzilla system for those that wish to have this feature:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=334052

Answer (score 24):

In Eclipse SDK (I use 3.6.2), to hide empty folders in the "Package Explorer":

At the top-right of the Package Explorer view, there's a downward-pointing triangle. If you hover your mouse pointer over it you'll see "View Menu".

1. Click the "View Menu"
2. Selected "Filters"
3. Put a check next to "Empty Packages"
4. Click OK

now your empty folders don't show any more.

Comment: This might works for java files/packages(I'm doing actionscript development), but my problem revolves around non-java files.  I'll have a bunch of img/swf directories that are filtered to not show any files, and I'm left with an empty directory.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem to be possible and could make for a good bug report.

As [bug 157336](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=157336) (build output contains unnecessary empty directories) [comments](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=157336#c14):

> "`foo/bar/`" is treated as "`foo/bar/**`".
>   So, as I understand it `foo/bar/**` should exclude the content of the directory and `foo/bar` should additionally exclude the directory itself.

Meaning you might have to add every empty directory yourself to the Exclude list, which is not practical.

Another solution would be to give **[Mylyn](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/)** a try and see if its **[task context](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Mylyn/User_Guide#Context)** switching could hide any folder you don't need in the current task for you.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like that bug was fixed ages ago.  I followed your advice and filed a new bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=334052

Comment: @Matt: excellent. I will include the result of that bug report in my answer whenever an update is made on it.